# How do I query my database for all rows where the timestamp value of a field is the most recent?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, time, timestamp

I have a database which gets populated with a bunch of rows often, these rows have a field in them called "catalogue_time" which is the timestamp at which my other program which fills the database started a new routine. So this program will add new rows, all of which will have a "catalogue_time" field that is the same. My question is how do I retrieve all the rows where the timestamp in "catalogue_time" is the most recent?

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY catalogue_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

and this gives me the most recent record as expected, I could get the number of most recent records in a previous query and then use it here but I was wondering if theres a way to do it all in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are after:

```
SELECT *
  FROM threads
  WHERE catalogue_time = (SELECT max(catalogue_time) FROM threads);
```

This will return more rows if more rows all have the most recent timestamp.

Comment: Nice, thanks this is the proper solution, mine had an unecessary ORDER BY at the end

Answer (score 2):

`DENSE_RANK()` can be used for this purpose.

```
SELECT * FROM
(  select t.*, dense_rank() OVER (  ORDER BY catalogue_time DESC ) AS rnk
   FROM threads t
) s WHERE rnk = 1
```

You may find several other solutions here is SO. I would suggest you to compare various solutions and use the most performant one.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b30d8e420487e624081d6ea4782aab0c)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example like this:

```
SELECT * FROM threads 
WHERE catalogue_time = (
    SELECT catalogue_time ORDER BY catalogue_time DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: this does not seem to work. I get older rows as well as the most recent ones

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM threads WHERE catalogue_time = (SELECT MAX(catalogue_time) FROM threads) ORDER BY catalogue_time
```

thanks everyone